# Upper sum is strictly subadditive

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Can you give me an example demonstrating that the [upper sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UpperSum.html) is strictly subadditive (i.e. (the upper sum of $f$) + (the upper sum of $g$) is strictly bigger than the upper sum of $(f+g)$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any partition you want. Pick one of the subintervals $I$ in the partition, and let $a$ and $b$ be two distinct points in $I$.  Define $f$ and $g$ as follows:

$$f(x) =
\cases{
1 & \text{if } x=a\cr
0 & \text{otherwise}
}$$

$$g(x) =
\cases{
1 & \text{if } x=b\cr
0 & \text{otherwise}
}$$

Then the suprema of $f$, $g$, and $f+g$ in $I$ are all 1.  So $(\text{the upper sum of }f+\text{the upper sum of }g)$ is 2 times the width of $I$, but $\text{the upper sum of }(f+g)$ is 1 times the width of $I$.